# Transition from swiftui to swift storyboard after firebaseauth

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I currently have a project where I added firebaseauth in swiftui but I need to transition to my main storyboard after authentication.

Here is a snipit:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Combine
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseAuth

struct SignInView: View {
    @State var pushActive = false
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: SignInViewModel
    
    init(state: AppState) {
        self.viewModel = SignInViewModel(authAPI: AuthService(), state: state)
    }
    
    
   var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(state: viewModel.state),
                           isActive: self.$pushActive) {
              EmptyView()
            }.hidden()
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                Text("Log in")
                    .modifier(TextModifier(font: UIConfiguration.titleFont,
                                           color: UIConfiguration.tintColor))
                    .padding(.leading, 25)
                    .padding(.bottom, 80)
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 25) {
                        CustomTextField(placeHolderText: "E-mail",
                                      text: $viewModel.email)
                        CustomTextField(placeHolderText: "Password",
                                      text: $viewModel.password,
                                      isPasswordType: true)
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 25)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 40) {
                        customButton(title: "Log In",
                                     backgroundColor: UIConfiguration.tintColor,
                                     action: { self.viewModel.login() })
                      
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.alert(item: self.$viewModel.statusViewModel) { status in
            Alert(title: Text(status.title),
                  message: Text(status.message),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
                    if status.title == "Successful" {
                        self.pushActive = true
                    }
                  }))
        }
    }
    
    private func customButton(title: String,
                              backgroundColor: UIColor,
                              action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Text(title)
                .modifier(ButtonModifier(font: UIConfiguration.buttonFont,
                                         color: backgroundColor,
                                         textColor: .white,
                                         width: 275,
                                         height: 55))
        }
    }
}
```

Currently after authentication it goes to a view called HomeView.. I tried a few different methods to point to my main storyboard named "main" with no success.

```
NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(state: viewModel.state),
                           isActive: self.$pushActive) {
```

Any tips on how to make this work? The name of my storyboardID is: "MainView" and the viewcontroller connected to this storyboard is "MainViewController"

Thank you!

Comment: `I tried a few different methods to point ...... .... with no success.` Please add what you have tried so far. What does not work? What error do you get? Where exactly do you struggle?

Comment: Replace the home view with a UIViewControllerRepresentable that instantiates the storyboard

Comment: I am with @loremipsum - if you don't have an existing storyboard, you need to instantiate it; also, the question doesn't really sound like it has anything to do with Firebase or Firebase Auth - it's more of UI question. "How do I use a Storyboard in a SwiftUI project"